# Reading multiple keyboard keypresses in Python (stdin?)

Tags: python, keyboard, listener

I am trying to read any combination of keys from the keyboard in Python.
This is via the terminal, so whatever library should use stdin. Requiring root is fine. I want to get any keyboard event pressed on the system.

I tried using the keyboard library, and trying:

```
import keyboard
import time

def key_press(key):
    if key.event_type == "down":
        print(key.name)

keyboard.on_press(key_press)

while True:
    time.sleep(.1)
```

However this will only print one key at a time. I don't know the combinations of keys that will be used beforehand. I was expecting 'key' on key_press to be a list, not just one key.

pygame seems to do this but that requires a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`pynput.keyboard`](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) module instead and keep track of which keys are currently pressed with a set:

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard

pressed = set()

def on_press(key):
    if key not in pressed:
        pressed.add(key)
        print(pressed)

def on_release(key):
    pressed.remove(key)
    print(pressed)

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```